# After installing Wubi to a different drive than Windows, why is my bootloader gone?

Tags: grub2, windows-7, wubi

I used the windows installer of ubuntu 12.04 to download and install Ubuntu. I remember installing Ubuntu in different drive than that which contains Windows-7, it asked me to restart and when I did, the boot manager was missing. Can anyone understand what could have happened here?
Right now, its not booting any OS.

Comment: the computer is booting or its not booting to any of OS?

Comment: see the edit plz!

Comment: what type of error do you have? Grub rescue > _ ?

Comment: BOOT MNGR MISSING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many possible reason.

1. Please double check your BIOS and make sure you boot-priority is OK to boot from your hard disk.
2. Second thing that can happen is somehow, the `Active` partition is set to a partition that is not containing the boot manager. (Active partition means , that holds the bootmanager file)

To Get back windows,

1. Put your windows dvd.
2. Repair it.

Hopefully you will be able to boot windows. Now uninstall wubi and try reinstalling.

(A advice: download ISO file from the site and put wubi.exe and ISO in same directory. this will help you to avoid big downloads. Don't use alter net dvds)

Comment: Can there be more than one active partitions? I mean can it happen that I must have changed the drive containing Ubuntu to Active partition and the drive containing Windows must have lost the active partition? and thanks about the advice, I was thinking to do the same!

Comment: no only one partition can be active.